# converting multiple same date rows into single for each date

Tags: sql-server

My table contains many data in a single date, I want to group that rows using date in the date time column and show it in a single row

actual output:

```
start time                 EndTime                   Downtimeid

-----------------------   ------------------         ----------------
```

2018-11-26 06:00:00.000       2018-11-26 08:00:00.000         1
2018-11-26 06:00:00.000          2018-11-26 08:06:00.000         1
2018-11-26 06:00:00.000          2018-11-26.......
2018-11-26 06:00:00.000
2018-11-26 06:00:00.000
2018-11-25 22:00:00.000
2018-11-25 22:00:00.000
2018-11-25 22:00:00.000
2018-11-25 22:00:00.000
2018-11-25 22:00:00.000
2018-11-25 14:00:00.000
2018-11-25 14:00:00.000
2018-11-25 14:00:00.000
expected output:

```
2018-11-26 06:00:00.000,    2018-11-26 08:00:00.000    1 
2018-11-25 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Please provide the query that you have tried. You can do Group By on date column.

Comment: Please add the table structure and sample data to your question such that others can **really** help

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  start_time 
FROM   tablename
GROUP BY start_time
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want time, You can use

```
SELECT  CAST(start_time AS DATE) 
FROM   tablename
GROUP BY CAST(start_time AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
select Start_Time
from ShowDate
Group by Start_Time
order by Start_Time desc
```